# jinja2: overload how the templates load all variables

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there a way to overload how jinja evaluates all variable expressions?

I want to change how the templating system evaluates all variables, in `{{ variable }}` expressions, and in `{% if variable %}` type statements as well (I'd like to make it load them from a specific location in a specific way, by name).

For instance, if someone puts `{{ this.is.a.test }}` in a template, I want to use jmespath (https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) to load the variable from a known dictionary in the context, instead of the normal route. It would pick "hello" from this dictionary:

```json
{
  "this": {
    "is": {
      "a": {
        "test": "hello"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would also evaluate to true: `{% if this.is.a.test == "hello" %}`

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: i dont understand the question .... but it sounds like you maybe want the `import` directive in jinja2 templates

Comment: @JoranBeasley no... updated question. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your dict in as the `context` and it will work out of the box.

```py
>>> from jinja2 import Environment
>>> env = Environment()
>>> template = env.from_string('{{ this.is.a.test }}')
>>> context = {
...   "this": {
...     "is": {
...       "a": {
...         "test": "hello"
...       }
...     }
...   }
... }
>>> print(template.render(**context))
hello
```

There are two factors which make this work. First, as Jinja's [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables) explains:

> You can use a dot (`.`) to access attributes of a variable in addition
> to the standard Python `__getitem__` “subscript” syntax (`[]`).
>
> The following lines do the same thing:
>
> ```
> {{ foo.bar }}
> {{ foo['bar'] }}
> ```

The second is the use of `**` when passing in a dictionary expands the first level to keywords and values. In other words, the following two lines are exactly the same:

```py
foo(**{'bar': 'baz'})
foo(bar='baz')
```

Of course, Jinja's [Template.render](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.Template.render) method simply accepts keywords as root level variables, so that gives you what you want.

Comment: This is very cool, but it's more of a literal solution to the example, it does not give me the ability to run every variable name through jmespath for evaluation, which is really what I'm after. I want to make use of all of the json traversal, like `foo.bar[*].name`, etc. Seems like maybe overriding the `context_class` on `Environment` may be a start?

Comment: I assumed your mention of jmespath was just to point to some library which has similar functionality, not that you must absolutely use that library. Perhaps your question is too broad then. I suggest exploring overriding the `context_class` and coming back with a more focused question if you get stuck.